# How can i active first tab in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I use this jquery code to show parts in tabs:

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        $(".tab_content:first").show();

    /* if in tab mode */
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
        $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#" + d_activeTab).fadeIn();

    });
    /* if in drawer mode */

    $(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

        $(".tab_content").hide();

        var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#" + d_activeTab).fadeIn();

        $(this).addClass("d_active");

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("active");
    });
    });
</script>
```

in desktop, i don't have any problem but in mobile mode, I want to display first tab content active. like this:

```
first section:
   -content
second section:
third section:
forth section:
```

my problem is, first tab is not active. searching in google and some stack questions didn't help me.

woocommerce html part:

```
<div class="tab_container">
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tabdescription">
<span>
توضیحات                </span>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</h3>
<div id="tabdescription" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
<div class="item-content-inner">

<h2>توضیحات</h2>
```

Comment: Try to trigger your click event on first li i.e : `$("ul.tabs li:first").trigger('click')` put this line in last see if that works .

Comment: @Swati you mean after this `$("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("active");` ?

Comment: It does not work

Comment: please show relevant html code

Comment: @Swati html part added

Comment: jQuery acts on HTML, not PHP. Please show the rendered HTML.

Comment: @Swati i just added html part, because of long html, i cutted it

Comment: anybody? somebody?